# Attempted to deploy to firebase on github branch

Tags: git, github, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have two branches my github repository https://github.com/sodewumi/EnTrack/tree/master.
The master works currently with `firebase` https://entrack.firebaseapp.com/

I'm trying to play with the code on my branch to update certain features branch: `geofire_map`

and I wanted to deploy the branch on a separate firebase database. 
When I am in the `geofire_map` branch I type in

```
firebase deploy
```

But when I do this, firebase updates the entrack.firebaseapp website with the code on my branch.

Can you have two separate firebase deploys for different branches within the same repo?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the command `firebase use <appAlias>`. Automatically, when you do `firebase init` the file *.firebaserc* will be generated with an alias (that you can change by creating new aliases).

Here is the Firebase documentation for this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#adding_a_project_alias

Follow these steps every time you need to deploy to a different branch:

- Checkout to the branch
- `firebase use <project_alias>`

Now all actions done with Firebase command will be to this project.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it will require some juggling.

Firebase keeps track of the Firebase application that a directory maps to in a file called `firebase.json` in that directory. So you can delete that file and run `firebase init` again to create a new one after switching branches. Then you can commit the `firebase.json` to each branch and things should work automatically from there on.

Alternatively you might want to consider keeping each branch in a separate directory.